# Normalisation and 0 padding

Tags: python, list, variables, normalization

How would I create a function for example normalist(x, y) that returns a list of numbers which is 'x', normalized so that the sum of the normalised list is 1.0 AND padded to contain 'y' elements. For example,

```
normalist([2,2,2,2,2], 5) => [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
normalist([5], 4)         => [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0].`
```

I don't know how to go about padding, and I'm trying to make normalist(x,y) so I can run the function against any list.

```
def normalist():

    list = [2, 2, 2, 2]
    s = sum(list)
    norm = [float(i)/s for i in list]
    return norm

print(normalist())
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Just edited to show what I have so far, sorry I'm extremely new.

Comment: The code you posted does not match the definition you gave.  The function must have two parameters.  For the most part, start with pencil & paper.  Figure out how *you* would do the task.  For instance, given [4, 3, 2, 1] and 5, how do *you* compute the return list?  Break that down into computational steps and try to program *that*.. The code you've given won't even execute.

Comment: Most of the time people want to see your code as you see it, meaning you would have to fix the format, For future reference, you can format your code by highlighting it and hitting `ctrl` + `k`

Comment: @Prune I have broken it down, I can explain what I'm trying to do but if I do it then the code won't run because I don't know how to code the second parameter in, so I've just tried to normalize a list first, please note I've been coding for a month, month and a half at max, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: @MooingRawr Thank you for the advice, I actually need a bit of help in posting questions hahaha

Comment: @Prune just edited it and indented it properly so it can run.

Comment: What happens if the length of the `list` is smaller than `n`?

Comment: @MooingRawr I'm just going to write an error message, so if list < n print error message

Answer (score 1):

How to Normalize your list:

```
def normalist(lst):
    s = sum(lst)
    norm = [float(i)/s for i in lst]
    return norm

lst = [2, 2, 2, 2]
print(normalist(lst))
```

Note we are passing in the `lst` instead of hard coding it in the function. Also refrain from naming variables key words such as `list`. Python allows this but it overrides some functions.

---

Added some `0.0` padding:

```
def normalist(lst, n):
    if len(lst) > n:
        print('length of list is bigger than n')
        return False
    s = sum(lst)
    norm = [float(i)/s for i in lst] + [0.0]*(n-len(lst))
    return norm

lst = [2, 2, 2, 2]
n = 5
print(normalist(lst,n))  #outputs [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0]
```

In Python we can use `+` to append or add lists together, the `[0.0]*(n-len(lst))` is basically saying: I want a list of `0.0` and I want `n - len(lst)` number of them. [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)  We also check if the size of the `lst` is smaller or equal to `n`, change this however you want your function to function.

Comment: Thank you firstly for teaching me how to edit with ctrl + k, secondly thank you informing me about the naming of variables, I straight up did not know that and lastly thank you for helping me with this, I didn't know that you could add lists like that and thats a very nice way of padding 0.0

Comment: As long as you are willing to change, that's all that matters. People on this site can come off as cold, but it's because they have seen so many badly answer questions. As you can see, if you just ask in the proper format and provide what you've tried and what went wrong, people will more than likely help. Good luck.

Comment: I'm so willing to learn to code, I've just struggled learning functions and how code actually runs, I've got a long way to go but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, let's get the parameters straight:

```
def normalist(in_list, n):

    s = sum(in_list)
    norm = [float(i)/s for i in in_list]
    return norm

print(normalist([4, 5, 2, 5], 4))
```

Output:

```
[0.25, 0.3125, 0.125, 0.3125]
```

---

Now, to pad, just compare **n** to the length of the list:

```
for extra in range(len(norm), n+1):
    # append a 0 to norm
```

Note that this will do nothing if **norm** is already long enough.

Comment: So far one of the things that interests me in coding is the different ways you can tackle something, there isn't a set solution. Thank you very much @Prune for your advice and help.